# What is a less campy way of saying "Treasure hunt"?

Tags: phrase-requests, slang

I've been trying to find a more modern way/phrase of expressing the idea of a treasure hunt and I am falling short. I've thought of "fortune-finding" but I'm hoping for something better.

**EDIT**: Sorry, I shot from the hip a little bit. Also, I guess there are other definitions of "campy" I wasn't aware of?

**Context**: Say I was thinking about hiding something on a trail or in a city and whoever finds it wins some money. And I want to tell the the outdoorsy/hiking community about it. I don't like "treasure hunt" because it feels a little too juvenile. I'm hoping for something that will convey a competitive/adventurous feel (race, expedition, sprint).

Comment: How about **fishing trip**?

Comment: Can you explain what criteria you will compare to choose a "better" answer? Welcome to ELU, by the way--do give some time to the [tour] if you haven't yet.

Comment: 'scavenger hunt' is more common nowadays.

Comment: Hmmhnn...You want "gay" but "not campy"? Or not gay? You need a lot more context here.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick replies everybody. My aversion to "Treasure Hunt" is that it has more a juvenile connotation in my mind. Is that just me? I'm hoping to capture something a bit more modern/adult. Like the patagonia/north face equivalent of what a treasure hunt would be.

Comment: It still seems that you have not caught onto other meanings of "campy"...what are you looking for? Do you mean like Boy Scouts and Campfire Girls?

Comment: All you have to do is decide how people will hunt and what treasure they will find. If you can write out those words, you will generate the words you need. Look there.

Comment: @BradyRiddle Welcome to ELU. Please see our [help on phrase requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info). There's a checklist at the bottom which you can use to frame your question. Hint: we need to know what you're looking for if we're to help you find it. What criteria will you use to choose the right answer? [Also, please edit your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/552614/edit) to include everything relevant **within the question.** Comments are ephemeral and no-one should have to trawl through them to find relevant detail. Thanks!

Comment: I think maybe you might be more happy with "treasure quest", where "treasure" coud also be replaced with something more specific, for example, "muffin". Bad example, as far as campy goes, since "muffin quest" might trigger your campy nose even more.

Comment: Some treasure hunts (or searches or quests) are not children’s games, but searches by archeologists or archivists, or searches of shipwrecks for treasure or historical artifacts. Often the finds are shared by the team or sponsors regardless of the individual who locates a specific item. So . . . what are you looking for?

Comment: These days they are called [geocaching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocaching),

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with geocaching but this isn't the same thing. The cache won't stay there. Once it's found it's gone.

Comment: Even after the edits, the title of the question remains confusing. It appears that *campy* in it is intended to mean something like camping-related, but the word is practically never used that way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

> treasure hunt

does have a slight nuance of appealing to a younger, preteen crowd, Robert Louis Stevenson and pirates and maps with an X. However, that nuance is only slight, so I think it would still work given that the situation is eactly that, looking for a treasure of some kind.

A less youthful sounding alternative might be:

> scavenger hunt.

It names the same activity, but is used for a wider age  demographic. It is often used as a label for a team building activity for groups at work. That doesn't mean immediately that it does not have a youthful nuance to it, but whatever nuance it does have, it is less youthful than 'treasure hunt'.

Answer (score 0):

A *Treasure hunt* is still a means of fun for the young at heart if not the soundest of sinew. I think what you are after is a *Targeted Search*. By this you mean a competitive goal oriented search for something of value. Being on a hiking trail you have selected your audience as those who are capable of and interested in such adventure as an outlet for their wanderlust. I can hardly wait.